# What is a partial multiset?

Tags: multisets

A. Rabinovich, and B. A. Trakhtenbrot, in their [*Behavior Structures and Nets*](https://dx.doi.org/10.3233/FI-1988-11404) paper, uses the expression "partial multiset" without defining it.

In context, they have an alphabet $\Sigma$, a finite multiset $A$ over $\Sigma$, and let $B \subset A$ be a "partial multiset".

Should that be read simply as [inclusion of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Basic_properties_and_operations)? They also discuss partial ordered multisets, but "partial" refers to the order, and not the multi-set.

Comment: I have asked the question on [mastodon](https://lipn.info/web/@clementaubert/109354420415316372) and a discussion followed. We conjecture that it means "the support of $B$ should be strictly included in the support of $A$".